# Return multiple vectors in OpenCL/C - Comparison of performance

Tags: c++, c, vector, opencl

I have a function `f(x,y)` that runs on a matrix with elements `(x,y)` and for each value produces two output vectors `a = [a0,a1,a2,a3]` and `b = [b0,b1,b2,b3]`. In a next step, there is a `sum A` over all `a(x,y)` and a `sum B` over all `b(x,y)`. In a last step, `A/B` is calculated. I understand, that in OpenCL as well as in C there are 3 basic approaches to tackle this problem:

1. Returning `a,b` as one combined `float8`, do the summation with these vectors, explicitly formulate the division.
2. Return an array of 8 floats, do the summation and division on the array elements.
3. Return a struct holding two vectors, summation and division using vectors.

My question is: Aside from the three approaches using different data types, what's the difference regarding their memory usage and performance?

Comment: Depends on the hardware imo. For example, float2 is better memory optimized(for speed) than float8 on a hd7870 (pitcairn gpu) but this may be opposite on a AVX2 capable cpu. Returning struct may be faster on a cpu while returning an array better on gpu. Do you have  a datasheet of your opencl device?

Comment: Common problem of OpenCL is that the performance is not portable and performance characteristics varies among implementations even on the same hardware. This question is impossible to answer without knowledge of the implementation and hardware.

Comment: "It is not possible to give an answer" in this case is a satisfying answer. Because it means for me to try and see.